# Fetching a distinct column only if duplicates columns have the same data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this type of table:

```
+-----TABLE1----+
| Name, Boolean |
| A   , 0       |
| B   , 0       |
| B   , 0       |
| A   , 1       |
| C   , 1       |
| D   , 0       |
| C   , 0       |
| A   , 0       |
| A   , 1       |
| B   , 0       |
| D   , 0       |
+--------------+
```

I want to select distinct all names that their duplicates booleans are 0 aswell.
So the result will be:

```
+---------------+
| RESULT:       |
| Name          |
| B             |
| D             |
+---------------+
```

Because A and C contains boolean also of "1" so they wont be fetched

I can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, MAX(boolean) as boolean FROM table1 GROUP BY name;
```

But what condition I need to use if I want to fetch only the results that their max(boolean) are 0?

I can't use two select statements inside one query because we are talking about big data database..
so this solution is not an option in my case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name FROM table1 t WHERE t1.name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.name FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.boolean = 1);
```

Couldn't think of an option when using "JOIN" aswell.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select name
from table1 t
group by name
having min(boolean) = max(boolean);
```